# OpenGL Collision Detection

Tags: opengl, graphics, jogl

I am currently working on designing my first FPS game using JOGL. (Java bindings for OpenGL).

So far I have been able to generate the 'world' (a series of cubes), and a player model. I have the collision detection between the player and the cubes working great.

Now I am trying to add in the guns. I have the gun models drawn correctly and loading onto player model. The first gun I'm trying to implement is a laser gun, which shoots and instantaneous line-of-sight laser at whatever you're aiming at. Before I work on implementing the enemy models, I would like to get the collision detection between the laser and the walls working.

My laser, currently, is drawn by a series of small cubes, one after the other. The first cube is drawn at the end of the players gun, then it draws continuously from there. The idea was to continue drawing the cubes of the laser until a collision was detected with something, namely the cubes in the world.

I know the locations of the cubes in the world. The problem is that I have to call glMatrixPush to draw my character model. The laser is then drawn within this modelview. Meaning that I have lost my old coordinate system - so I'm drawing the world in one system, then the lazer in another. Within this player matrix, I have go call glRotate and glTranslate several times, in order to sync everything up with the way the camera is rotating. The lazer is then built by translating along the z-axis of this new system.

My problem is that through all of these transformations, I no longer have any idea where my laser exists in the map coordinate system, primarily due to the rotations involving the camera.

Does anyone know of a method - or have any ideas, for how to solve this problem? I believe I need a way to convert the new coordinates of the laser into the old coordinates of the map, but I'm not sure how to go about undoing all of the transformations that have been done to it. There may also be some functionality provided by OpenGL to handle this sort of problem that I'm just unaware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point that was being made in the first answer is that you should never depend on the matrix to position the object in the first place.  You should be keeping track of the position and rotation of the laser before you even think about drawing it.  Then you use the translate and rotate commands to put it where you know it should be.

You're trying to do things backwards, and yes, that does mean you'll have to do the matrix math, and OpenGL doesn't keep track of that because the ModelView matrix is the ONLY thing that OpenGL does keep track of in regards to object positions.  OpenGL has no concept of "world space" or "camera space".  There is only the matrix that all input is multiplied by.  It's elegantly simple...  but in some cases I do prefer the way DirectX has a a separate view matrix and model matrix.

So, if you don't know where an object is located without matrix math, then I would consider that a fundamental design problem.  If you don't *need* to know the object position, then matrix-transform to your hearts content, but if you do need it's position, *start* with the position.

(pretty much what the first answer says, just in a different way...)

Comment: +1 I think you explained it that part of the problem better than I did :)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be considering the laser as a spacial child of the character that fires it. Once its been fired, the laser is an entity of its own, so you should render as follows:

```
glPushMatrix(viewMatrix);
glPushMatrix(playerMatrix);
DrawPlayer();
glPopMatrix();
glPushMatrix(laserMatrix);
DrawLaser();
glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();
```

Also, be sure that you don't mix your rendering transformation logic with the game logic. You should always store the world-space position of your objects to be able to test for intersections regardless of your current OpenGL matrix stack.

Remember to be careful with spacial parent/child relationships. In practice, they aren't that frequent. For more information, google about the problems of scene graphs.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've made some changes and I'm now rendering the laser in it's own matrix. Is there a standard or nice way of saving the world space position of a new object? For example - since I've already pushed my viewMatrix, and my playerMatrix, whenever I go to push my laserMatrix, how do I know where that is in the world space?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you here. `glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)` can retrieve your current matrix, if that's what you need, but you should always know where your laser is in world space because your laser entity class should store that value. The laser's transformation matrix should be computed from its world-space position. Once again, the current OpenGL matrix stack state should not impact your ability to locate your entities in world space.

Comment: So in order to store the world-space coordinates of my objects, each time I call something like glRotate or glTranslate, I will need to do the matrix math myself - multiplying by the inverse matrix - to keep track of the world-space coordinates? It seems odd that OpenGL wouldn't keep track of that itself.